# Can't access public static class from another namespace

Tags: c#

```
namespace PROJ.Service {
   public static class ExceptionDatesUpdateService {
        public static ExceptionDatesUpdateService()
        {
        }

        public static bool IsServiceRunning() {
            return _updateThread != null && _updateThread.IsAlive;
        }
   }
}
```

When I try to use a static class above, it says it is not accessible. Why? The reference exists.

```
using PROJ.Service;
namespace PROJ.admin {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    bool ch = ExceptionDatesUpdateService.IsServiceRunning();
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone. The problem was found. When I solved other errors and compile it. It dissappeared. I am new to c#, sorry for fool question. :)

Comment: Please post exact error (consider to search for error code - most CSXXXX compiler errors have explanations on MSDN)

Comment: where is `_updateThread` defined?

Comment: As Alexei says, please post the complete error.  You had 'error 42' up here before but I think that was error number 42, not the code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've added the appropriate project reference, one problem I see is that static type initializers cannot have access modifiers. Try this:

```
public static class ExceptionDatesUpdateService {
    static ExceptionDatesUpdateService()
    {
    }
}
```

Of course, if there's nothing inside the initializer, you can just remove it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by different .NET framework versions being set in the project properties. For instance, one project may be .NET 3.5 and you're trying to reference a .NET 4.0 project.

It can also be caused by a similar x64 vs x86 mismatch.

Usually the reference itself will have a warning icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Target Framework is same in the project properties for both the projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace PROJ.admin 
{
    public static class NewClass
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            bool ch = ExceptionDatesUpdateService.IsServiceRunning();
        }
    }
}
```

Try this is working